# need to print two different strings from a text file using tcl script

Tags: tcl

I have arequirement to get two different strings from two consecutive lines from a file using tcl script
I tried following but it doesn't work.
So here below i need to print string "Clock" and "b0". I am able to print Clock. but i need both "clock" "b0"

```
set f [eval exec "cat src.txt"]
set linenumber 0

while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    incr linenumber
    if {[string match "Clock" $line] >= 0 } {
        # ignore by just going straight to the next loop iteration
        while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
            incr linenumber
            if { [string match "b0" $line"]} {
                close $out
                puts "final $line"
            }      
            puts "\n$line"
            continue
        }
    }
}
close $f
```

Comment: You're sure this prints only clock? It looks to me this would just fail horribly, it even has syntax errors.

Comment: KillianDS is right. `gets` work on file descriptors, not strings. If this code works at all it works by accident.

Comment: linenumber variable is for?

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
set f [open "src.txt" r]; # opening file

while {![eof $f] >= 0} {
    set line [gets $f]; # reading line from file
    if {[string match "*Clock*" $line]} {
        ; # if Clock found
        puts $line
        set line [gets $f]; # reading next line from file
        if { [string match "*b0*" $line]} {
            ; # if b0 found
            puts "final $line"
        }
    } 
}
close $f
```